# TFS migrating from TFVC to Git

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

Me and my team were using TFS 2015, using TFVC.
We installed TFS 2018 and we are moving our projects to TFS 2018.
We'd like to use Git instead of TFVC.

Can we do this easly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in TFS migration:

[image]

[image]

In this way, you can keep the history only of the last 180 days.

Another option is to use [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), the git-tfs tool is a two-way bridge between Team Foundation Version Control and Git, and can be used to perform a migration. Git-TFS is appropriate if you want to attempt a migration with full history, more than the 180 days that the Import tool supports, or if you want to attempt a migration that includes multiple branches and merge relationships.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git).

Comment: Using the built-in TFS migration, will I be able to move my TFV repo to Git?

Comment: Yes, did you try?

Comment: Yes, but I am having issues in the path... My TFS 2015 is a machine and my TFS 2018 is in another machine. How should I choose the path? Both machines can communicate

Comment: You can’t migrate tfvc from 2015 to git in 2018. You need migrate 2015 to git and move the git to 2018 or move tfvc to 2018 and migrate to git.

Comment: Ok. So I can migrate TFVC to GIt in TFS 2015 using the built-in TFS migration right? After that how can I move my git to TFS 2018 in another machine?

Comment: I don’t think in 2015 the built in migration exist :/ can you check? If not, you need use git-tfs tool.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without the git-tfs tool? I just need to copy a few files and folders from TFS 2015 (TFVC) to TFS 2018 (Git). I don't need the history.

Comment: If you don’t need the history is not a problem, create a new folder, copy the folders and the files to there, run ‘git unit’ go tfs 2018, create a new git repo and follow the instructions how to push.

Comment: You mean I clone my existing repo in TFS 2018 with git. Than add the files. The commit and push? Using git in command line

Comment: Ok. This cannot be achieved only by the UI?